# Firestore emulator performance vs actual

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have setup the firebase local emulator and created a project with cloud functions and firestore. I also exported my production data to the project which I import into the emulator. (the collection in question is about 5000 documents ranging from 5kb to 200kb in size)

My goal was to benchmark query performance, so I wrote a query and ran it a number of times to get an average execution time of 130 ms. I then wrote a different query to get an average execution time of 20 ms. I did not import any indexes (the admin sdk doesn't seem to require them when querying the emulator like it does what querying production).

I also observed the first query always takes significantly longer.

My question is basically, how does this difference in execution time translation to the production environment if at all. Assuming the **same** queries are run against the **same** data, and **ignoring network latency** to/from the client. Will the second query run about ~110ms faster? Or will the difference be less/more?

Also why does the first query take longer, and is there any way to use that fact to improve performance in real world usage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> how does this difference in execution time translation to the production environment if at all.

The observed performance of the emulator has little to nothing to do with the performance of the actual cloud hosted product.  It's not the same code, and it's not running on the same set of computing resources.

Firestore is massively scalable and shards your data across many computing resources, all of which work together to service a query and ensure that it performs at any scale.  As you can imagine, an emulator running on your one local machine is nowhere near that.  They are simply not comparable.

The emulator is meant to ease local development without requiring the use of paid cloud resources to get your job done.  It's not meant for any other purpose.

Comment: Could you shed some light on why the first query run on the emulator takes longer than subsequent runs of the same query? And does this happen in production as well?

Comment: The emulator is open source, and you can benchmark its operations from a very detailed perspective using whatever node-based performance monitoring tools you would like. Again, the emulator does not share code with the cloud service, so you should not expect the exact same behavior.  But you can also benchmark its performance from the perspective of your client app if you want.